# .htaccess 301 redirecting sub-sub directory URLs to fixed sub dir url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all of the following URLs:

```
/blog/blog/this-is-an-example-page/
/blog/blog/hello-how-are-you/
/blog/blog/2015/04/29/old-article/
/blog/blog/2014/09/12/
```

To the following dir:

```
/blog/
```

And simply lose the rest of the URL. So, `/blog/blog/this-is-an-example-page/` does NOT go to `/blog/this-is-an-example-page/`, but to `/blog/`. This is the line in my .htaccess file that should do this, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/blog/(.*)$ /blog/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

This is the full .htaccess file content:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Force https and www
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.easterisland.travel/blog/$1 [R,L]


# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
# END WordPress

RewriteRule ^blog/blog/(.*)$ /blog/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

**This file is located in the /blog/ dir.**

What am I doing wrong? Why is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to match against the folder the htaccess file is located in, try :

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ /blog/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Try this htacess :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
    # Force https and www
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.easterisland.travel/blog/$1 [R,L]
  # BEGIN WordPress
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ /blog/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it unfortunately doens't work!

Comment: Almost, my friend! We're getting close. It's redirecting now, but it's remembering the part of the URL after /blog/blog/*, and I'd like for it to cut it right off. So, /blog/blog/this-is-an-example-page/ does NOT go to /blog/this-is-an-example-page/, but to /blog/.

Comment: Works perfectly well, thank you! Please note that you missed updating the code at the top, the first, single line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Keep redirect rules before other rules and fix your `www + https` rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Force https and www
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.easterisland.travel/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^blog/blog/(.*)$ /blog/ [R=301,L,NC]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache completely when testing this change.

Comment: Thank you for that, but it still doesn't work. I'm using Chrome, opening up a new private session window every time to make sure nothing is cached. I'm trying to enter this URL https://www.easterisland.travel/blog/blog/laksjdflkasjdf/lkajsf/ but no news.

Comment: Thanks for being helpful with the correct www + https rule! Plus 1